# How to get the url of the server with java cdi without JSF

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, cdi

My app is an Java REST app, and i need to send e-mails.

The e-mail has the **URL** for the related action...

How can i get the real server address????

I can get the Session instance, but it has only the contextPath...

```
http://xxxxxx/<contextPath>
```

I need the fully context... like this

```
<protocol>://<domain>/<contextPath>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45525/7076

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java EE 7 / CDI 1.1+ you can inject `ServletContext` for the application and `HttpServletRequest` for the current request :

```
@Inject
ServletContext context;

@Inject
HttpServletRequest request;
```

You'll have what you need in these to build your URL.

If you are on Java EE 6 / CDI 1.0 the easiest solution is to add [Apache Deltaspike servlet module](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation.html#servlet-module) to your project, then you'll have the same feature with :

```
@Inject
@Deltaspike
ServletContext context;

@Inject
@Deltaspike
HttpServletRequest request;
```